# C# VTK plot/mark 3D points with different symbols?

Tags: c#, c++, vtk

I'm working on a project in C# using VTk - plotting some 3D objects (that works fine) and also plotting some points (also works fine). But I did not find anything for the following requierement:

As the points belong to different objects we want the points to have different shapes (like rectangle, star, cross,...). I came across vtkPlotPoints that do have this option (but I don't have a plot) but not normal vtkPoints.

Is there any way to give vtkPoints different shapes or do I have to use another vtkObject type?